# Tomcat 6 performance tuning

Tags: tomcat6

I am planning on using Apache Tomcat 6.0 as web server in my web application.  I have written my apps that it calls some ajax request/http request alternately.

Can you share with me some tutorials on what items can I do to enhance the performance of my Tomcat when I release my web application to the users?

I am hoping Tomcat can support my web application which I think has so many ajax request running at the background.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab a copy of Professional Apache Tomcat 6 from Wrox. It's a decent book that'll introduce you to administrating a Tomcat Server, including performance ideas.

Here's a few to start with:

1. [Enable APR libraries](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html)-Windows: put the [tcNative.dll](http://apr.apache.org/) into your catalina path. Linux-Usually already has this, but you can build from source if needed. Configure your server.xml if neccessary. That's it.
2. [Set up connection pooling](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)-Rather than get a new connection every time, have Tomcat manage your connection pooling.
3. [Turn on compression/caching](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html)-It'd be better to do this with an Apache frontend, but if you are serving directly from tomcat, this'll cut down on response size, # of requests, etc.